# JSON.parse reviver function nested objects

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, reviver-function

My goal is to tell the `JSON.parse` function with the optional `reviver argument` that I would like it if the string being passed to the `calc(string)` function has a key named `"expr"` to perform the operation inside of that expression, and then continue to work outwards to operate on the rest of the string.

Every time I run this I am getting `NaN`.

If I comment out the two last `calc(string)` calls before `console.log(initNumber)` then the program runs as expected.

So if the key is `"expr"` and the value of the nested `"op"` key is `"add"` then perform the add() function on that nested object. Same goes for if the `"op"` key is `"subtract"`.

Any help is immensely appreciated.

```
var initNum = 0;

var calc = function(string) {
    var calcString = JSON.parse(string, reviver);

    add(calcString);
    subtract(calcString);
};

var add = function(string) {
    if (string["op"] == "add") {
    var numString = parseInt(JSON.stringify(string["number"]));
    initNum = numString + initNum;
    return initNum;
  }
}
var subtract = function(string) {
    if (string["op"] == "subtract") {
    var numString = parseInt(JSON.stringify(string["number"]));
    initNum = initNum - numString;
    return initNum;
  }
}

var reviver = function(key, val) {
  if (key == "expr") {
    if (val.op == "add") {
      return add(val);
    }
    else if (val.op == "subtract") {
      return subtract(val);
    }
  }
    else {
      return val;
    }
};

calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 5}');
calc('{"op" : "subtract", "number" : 2}');
calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 19}');
calc('{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}');
calc('{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}');
console.log(initNum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points :

- `reviver` will give you the already parsed values, you don't need to parse them again.
- if you convert an `expr` into a value, your `add` and `subtract` functions need to be able to read those values, and not just `number` - I think, maybe you intend for different logic. That's why I get `operand` the way I do below. Either way, you need to be aware that there might not be a `number` argument, and handle that.
- the reason you were getting `NaN` is because of the above- you were trying to get the `number` from objects which didn't have one(the results of reviving `expr`s), which gives you `undefined` which broke the calculations.

Basically, remember that

`{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}`

goes to

`{"op": "subtract", "expr" : 37}`

after you revive the expression, so you need to handle that.

```js
var initNum = 0;

var calc = function(string) {
    var calcObj = JSON.parse(string, reviver);

    add(calcObj);
    subtract(calcObj);
};

var add = function(obj) {
    if (obj["op"] == "add") {
      var operand = (obj["number"])? obj["number"] : obj["expr"];
      initNum = operand + initNum;
      console.log("running total : "+initNum);
      return initNum;
  }
}
var subtract = function(obj) {
    if (obj["op"] == "subtract") {
      var operand = (obj["number"])? obj["number"] : obj["expr"];
      initNum = initNum - operand;
      console.log("running total : "+initNum);
      return initNum;
  }
}

var reviver = function(key, val) {
  if (key == "expr") {
    if (val.op == "add") {
      return add(val);
    }
    else if (val.op == "subtract") {
      return subtract(val);
    }
  }
    else {
      return val;
    }
};

calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 5}');
calc('{"op" : "subtract", "number" : 2}');
calc('{"op" : "add", "number" : 19}');
calc('{"op": "subtract", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "number" : 15}}');
calc('{"op": "add", "expr" : {"op" : "add", "expr" : {"op" : "subtract", "number" : 3}}}');
console.log(initNum);
```

Comment: thank you so much. That makes wayyyyyyy more sense now. So in the var operand part, you're now saying that "If the JSON object has a "number" key, use that, otherwise use the "expr" key." Thank you thank you.

Comment: `If the JSON object has a "number" key, use that, otherwise use the "expr" key` Yes, exactly. And because `reviver` is [defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) to work 'beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself', all `expr`s should be already converted to their values by the time they are seen by the `add` or `subtract` operation surrounding them.

Comment: Just brilliant. Makes total sense. :)